# Merging datasets with xarray makes variables to be nan

Tags: python, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray, array-merge

I want to represent in the same plot two datasets, so I am merging them using xarray. These is how they look like:

**ds1**

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 1, lat: 1037, lon: 1345)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 37.7 37.7 37.69 37.69 37.69 ... 35.01 35.01 35.0 35.0
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-11-23
  * lon      (lon) float32 -9.001 -8.999 -8.996 -8.993 ... -5.507 -5.504 -5.501
Data variables:
    CHL      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

**ds2**

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 1, lat: 852, lon: 1168)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-11-23
  * lat      (lat) float32 35.0 35.0 35.01 35.01 35.01 ... 37.29 37.29 37.3 37.3
  * lon      (lon) float32 -5.501 -5.498 -5.494 -5.491 ... -1.507 -1.503 -1.5
Data variables:
    CHL      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

So then I use:

```
ds3 = xr.merge([ds1,ds2])
```

It works for the dimensions, but my variable CHL becomes nan:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 1887, lon: 2513, time: 1)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 35.0 35.0 35.0 35.0 35.01 ... 37.69 37.69 37.7 37.7
  * lon      (lon) float64 -9.001 -8.999 -8.996 -8.993 ... -1.507 -1.503 -1.5
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-11-23
Data variables:
    CHL      (time, lat, lon) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
```

So when I plot this dataset I have the following result:

[image: bug]

I assume those white stripes are caused by the variable CHL becoming nan...

Any ideas of what could be happening? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the NaN values are the missing values in the original dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any values *become* NaNs. Rather, I think that the latitude coordinates simply differ. Because you do an outer join (the default for `xr.merge`), xarray has to fill up the matrix at places where there is no information about the values. The default for the `fill_value` seems to be NaN.
So the question is, what values would you expect in these locations?
One possibility could be to fill the missing places by interpolation. In several dimensions this might be tricky, but as far as I see you are just placing two images next to each other with no overlap in the `lon` dimension.
In that case, xarray lets you interpolate the `lat` dimension easily:

```
ds3["CHL"].interpolate_na(dim="lat", method="linear")
```